# How to converting json into gson model for retrofit

Tags: java, json, retrofit2, android, gson

I'm having a hard time understanding what steps i need to take to get the following [json](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=) into a usable model for retrofit (POJO). I can handle the raw Json easily but I'm truing to get it to work with Gson so that i can pass the response i receive from retrofit to it.

Any information, tutorials, examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org will help?

Comment: I've used that for my other query when there was only one layer. But when the data I'm after is deeper down, how would you extract that?